# A strange assumption Yukawa potential based on

Tags: quantum-field-theory, forces, potential, time

I'm reading A.Zee's Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell recently and there is something that confused me.

At  Page27 PartI.4 named 'From particle to force' where he deduces Yukawa potential, **He used an assumption that$J(x)=J_1(x_1)+J_2(x_2)$ is time-independent.**

Of course, with mathematical rigor, you will reach the conclusion, the Yukawa potential$E=-\frac{1}{4\pi r}e^{-mr}$.

However, in reality, **two particles will move, which means the $J(x)$ would not be rigorously time-independent!!**

So, **does it mean that the Yukawa potential is just a good approximation rather than a rigorous conclusion?**

Further, is there a **theory describing the potential between two moving particles in QFT?**

Comment: The Yukawa potential is by definition a static potential. For a moving source, you may be interested in [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Feynman_propagator). Or you can do yourself the calculation...

Comment: Thank you, I will try for moving source. I made a mistake that during the deduction, I somehow wrongly take the integrate of $k_0$ from -∞ to ∞, to be the integrate of time, which made this question.